# How do you implement type-checking on methods for classes that inherit from NamedTuple in mypy?

Tags: python, typechecking, namedtuple, mypy

According to the mypy docs, if a class needs to reference itself, it can use a [forward-reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-problem-of-forward-declarations).

This seems to work fine for normal classes but I'm having trouble getting it to work with classes that inherit from NamedTuple.

```
"""
All this code runs without error on Python 3.6 

The question is why the 'B' class' __add__ method
raises an error through mypy.
"""


from typing import *

class A:
    def __init__(self, x: int) -> None:
        self.x = x

    def __add__(self, other: 'A') -> 'A':
        return type(self)(self.x + other.x)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'A(x={self.x})'

A1 = A(1)
A2 = A(2)
A3 = A1 + A2
print(A3)

class B(NamedTuple('B', [('x', int)])):

    # The following line will raise an error in mypy
    # error: Argument 1 of "__add__" incompatible with supertype "tuple"
    def __add__(self, other: 'B') -> 'B':
        return type(self)(self.x + other.x)

B1 = B(1)
B2 = B(2)
B3 = B1 + B2
print(B3)
```

Update: Guido van Rossum himself has since answered [this question on Github](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2954).

> I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish, but on the basis of your initial example I'm guessing you want to redefine + for class B to implement element-wise addition on instances of B. The reason mypy doesn't support this by default is something called the "Liskov substitution principle" (you can Google it for an explanation).
>
> However there's a work-around: put # type: ignore on the line that produces the error (the def **add** line). This is not sound but it will do what you want as long as you never pass a B instance to code that assumes it's a tuple and attempts tuple concatenation on it.

Comment: This is weird. Note, that `class B` is inheriting from a class with `__name__` 'B' already... maybe that is messing things up. So the `__mro__` is going to be something like `(<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class 'tuple'>, <class 'object'>)`

Comment: Try changing the name of `B`, or the name you pass to `namedtuple` . So something like `class B(NamedTuple('SuperB', [('x', int)])):
`

Comment: This might be relevant: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1237

Comment: Guido van Rossum's answer: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2954

Answer (score 1):

The type declaration for `B.__add__` suggests that it's only valid to add an instance of `B` to another instance of `B` (and the implementation backs that up, since it expects `other.x` to work). However, that method overrides the more general `__add__` method that comes from `tuple` (via `namedtuple`), which can concatenate any two tuples together (so the right-hand-side can be an instance of `tuple` or any `tuple`-subclass). Because your new method has a tighter type requirement for its argument, your class is (from `mypy`'s perspective) not a proper subclass of `tuple`. You can't drop an instance of your class into a place where a tuple was previously used, and have it work the same way.

Consider this function:

```
def tuple_append(tup: tuple, value: any) -> tuple:
     return tup1 + (value,)
```

This will work for normal tuples, but if you pass one of your `B` instances as `tup`, it will fail (even though you are passing in an instance of a `tuple` subclass as the function's type declaration requires). This is why `mypy` doesn't consider your `B` type to be valid. If it accepted `B`, other code with correct type declarations could break unexpectedly.

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a good way around this issue. Python doesn't have a notion of "private inheritance" that some other languages do. There's no way to inherit an implementation from another class without also publicly becoming an subclass.